# How do I render a blog post as an array instead of an object in a Nextjs/Sanity Studio Blog?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, next.js, sanity

This is my error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, categories, title, _updatedAt, author, _createdAt, _rev, slug, _type}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I'm trying to render a dummy blog post on `page.tsx`. If I enter the dummy blog post in Sanity Studio backend, the error is thrown. If there is no post in the Sanity Studio backend, no error is thrown.

page.tsx:

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import PreviewSuspense from '../components/PreviewSuspense'
import { DocumentsCount, query } from '../components/DocumentsCount'
import PreviewDocumentsCount from '../components/PreviewDocumentsCount'
import PreviewBlogList from '../components/PreviewBlogList'
import { client } from '../../lib/client'
import { cache } from 'react'
import BlogList from '../components/BlogList'

// Enable NextJS to cache and dedupe queries
const clientFetch = cache(client.fetch.bind(client))

export default async function HomePage() {
    // Check if next preview data cookie is present
    if (cookies().get('__next_preview_data')) {
        return (
            <PreviewSuspense fallback="Loading...">
                <PreviewDocumentsCount />
                <div>Preview Mode</div>
                <PreviewBlogList query={query} />
            </PreviewSuspense>
        )
    }

    const response = await clientFetch(query)
    const posts = Array.isArray(response) ? response : []

    if (!posts || posts.length === 0) {
        return <div>No posts available.</div>
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <DocumentsCount data={posts} />
            <br />
            Not in Preview Mode
            <BlogList posts={posts} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

DocumentsCount.tsx:

```
import groq from 'groq'

export const query = groq`
*[_type=='post'] {
  ...,
  author->,
  categories[]->
} | order(_createdAt desc)
`

export function DocumentsCount({ data }: any) {
    return (
        <>
            Documents: <strong>{data}</strong>
        </>
    )
}
```

PreviewDocumentsCount.tsx:

```
'use client'

import { usePreview } from '../../lib/preview'
import { query, DocumentsCount } from '../components/DocumentsCount'

export default function PreviewDocumentsCount() {
    const data = usePreview(null, query)
    return <DocumentsCount data={data} />
}
```

BlogList.tsx:

```
type Props = {
    posts: Post[]
}

function BlogList({ posts }: Props) {
    return <div>BlogList</div>
}

export default BlogList
```

PreviewBlogList.tsx:

```
'use client'

import { usePreview } from '@/lib/preview'
import BlogList from './BlogList'

type Props = {
    query: string
}

export default function PreviewBlogList({ query }: Props) {
    const posts = usePreview(null, query)
    // console.log('Loading Posts...', posts)
    return <BlogList posts={posts} />
}
```

typings.d.ts:

```
type Base = {
  _createdAt: string
  _id: string
  _rev: string
  _type: string
  _updatedAt: string
}

interface Post extends Base {
  author: Author
  body: Block[]
  categories: Category[]
  mainImage: Image
  slug: Slug
  title: string
  description: string
}

interface Author extends Base {
  bio: Block[]
  image: Image
  name: string
  slug: Slug
}

interface Image {
  _type: "image"
  asset: Reference
}

interface Reference {
  _ref: string
  _type: "reference"
}

interface Slug {
  _type: "slug"
  current: string
}

interface Block {
  _key: string
  _type: "block"
  children: Span[]
  markDefs: any[]
  style: "normal" | "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "blockquote"
}

interface Span {
  _key: string
  _type: "span"
  marks: string[]
  text: string
}

interface Category extends Base {
  description: string
  title: string
}

interface MainImage {
  _type: "image"
  current: string
}

interface Title {
  _type: "string"
  current: string
}
```

I've tried a couple ways to render the post as an array. I've tried using `Object.values()` on the `DocumentsCount` and `PreviewDocumentsCount` component but the error persists. My current code uses `isArray` to render the response as an array.

Comment: if that `data` that you are putting in `DocumentsCount` is an object, then no matter what method you try, it will throw the same error, because `Objects are not valid as a React child`, which means YOU CANNOT PUT AN OBJECT IN THE JSX.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It is clear that 'YOU CANNOT PUT AN OBJECT IN THE JSX', as you have stated (the error I referenced at the top of the question also states this). What is not clear is how to render the object as an array, so I asked.

Did you have something to offer that actually addresses the question?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you are trying to render object as an array ? Also, can you add the sample object ? I would suggest using `Object.values()` to get all the values from the object and mapping on it, but looks like you have already tried it.